# Error sending Content_Tags while posting a video using FB API

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, facebook-graph-api, request

I have tried many different ways but to no avail

API Spec - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/

Param - content_tags ( list  ) --> is what required

Below is my form data that is being posted

```
const formData = {
file_url: postOptions.filepath,
title: postOptions.title,
description: postOptions.description,
content_tags: ['tags', 'hello', 'hi']
};
```

HTTP Request Options

```
const options = {
url: https://graph-video.facebook.com/v9.0/${pageId}/videos?access_token=${accessToken},
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
Connection: 'keep-alive',
},
formData,
};
```

Error response returned.

```
{"error":
 {
 "message":"(#100) Param content_tags[0] must be a valid ID string (e.g., \"123\")",
 "type":"OAuthException",
 "code":100,
 "fbtrace_id":"ANoCbTSnh4uL960SjyE6XBV"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, seems it has to be not just any string but NUMBER string which are predefined IDs of the tag `list<numeric string>`

From [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video)

```
Tags that describe the contents of the video. Use search endpoint with type=adinterest to get possible IDs.
```

```
Example:
~~~~
/search?type=adinterest&q=couscous
~~~~
```

Here's full path of the above example shown by facebook, how you can get some IDs:
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=​"home"&limit =10&access_token={{access_token}}`

Answer (score 0):

you can capture facebook request when edit post to get list content_tags id like this
[image]